# I just deleted a Gist. Can I restore it using a clone?

Tags: gist

I created a Gist and `git clone`d it to my computer to work on it for a while. Eventually, I deleted it from the Gist website. Now I've decided I want it back. Is there any way to restore it using the local copy of the Git repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new Gist (the filenames and contents don't matter; they'll be replaced). Pull up a terminal and `cd` into the local repository, then set the `origin` URI to that of the new Gist and do a force-push. For example:

```
git remote set-url origin git@gist.github.com:/78eb4ef6a41dcd7ae036.git
git push --force origin master
```

After this, the new Gist should look exactly like the deleted one, down to the timestamps.

**WARNING:** Don't use force-pushes lightly! They clobber the remote repository *completely*, revision history and all. That's fine here, because you're force-pushing to an essentially empty repository, but in other cases it's almost certainly not what you want to do.

---

Thanks to wolfyshy from [Canternet](https://www.canternet.org) for coming up with this trick.